# Database Size Management

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am in the final stages of building my website and I am getting a little nervous that I am doing something wrong with my database.

I am building a Laravel/mysql site that allows users to add events. So I have an Event database. I allow users to choose dates for their event for next six months. That means one Event can have around 180 event dates which I save to a separate database called Shows. Each of those show dates can have tickets and the prices(vip, general etc) in a Ticket database. That means for just one event, it could create a huge number of entries.

```
event(1) -> show on every day(180) -> 5 ticket types(900 entries in my tickets database)
```

As far as I can tell this is the correct way to do it, but it seems like my Ticket database is going to get massive quickly. I will be using Elastic Search to filter through the data.

Comment: Can you get rid of the `Show` table and store the show date in the `Ticket` table? Otherwise I think it's the way to go.

Comment: I do suppose that each ticket could have a date. When I use elastic search to filter my events by date, it would have to search through 900 tickets per show instead of 180 shows.